# How to add data-option in <a /> from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to add data-option in anchor tag.

here what i have done so far

```
StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
DataTable dt1 = BAL.setDropDown(tablename, id_col, value_col);

if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
    {
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Li);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Tabindex, "-1");
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, "#");
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.data-option, row[0].ToString());
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A);
        writer.Write(row[1].ToString());
        writer.RenderEndTag();

        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }
}
```

i am having problem with

```
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.data-option, row[0].ToString());
```

this Line

i want to generate

```
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="1">Option 1</a></li>
```

Please Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add custom attributes using `(String, String)` overload:

```
writer.AddAttribute("data-option", "1");
```

Comment: Short and sweet.God Bless you!